# where to put persistentStoreDescriptions ? in Swift3 Coredata Boilerplate Stack

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, core-data-migration

I migrated my Coredata to new version and I put persistentStoreDescriptions 
before loadPersistentStores and app does not crash but does not persist data with the consideration that it was working well prior to migration here is my code:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreTest3")

    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()

    description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
    description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]


    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })


    return container
}()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, you have to specify the URL of your managed object model when initializing the persistent store description:

```
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
```

*To get the URL, check out* `Bundle.URL(forResource:withExtension)`

Comment: thanks I found it before seeing your answer this was the exact issue I have put: let urlStore = directory.appendingPathComponent("MYAPPName.sqlite")  description.url = urlStore

Comment: BTW thanks it is the answer, GREAT, struggle it like 3 or 4 days

Comment: I'm having this same problem and cannot seem to get this part to work correctly. What is the `directory` in the comment from @flu?